# How to abstract network model fetching

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

Instead of putting network model loading in every controller, I'm trying to abstract it in only one controller `ModelLoader`

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
protocol ModelLoaderDelegate: class {
    func didFetch(model: Any)
    func modelFailedToFetch(errorMessage: String)
}

final class ModelLoader<ModelType> {

    let api: API
    weak var delegate: ModelLoaderDelegate?
    private let client = dependencies.client

    init(api: API) {
        self.api = api
    }

    func fetchModel() {
        client.performRequest(api: api, decodeTo: ModelType.self, completion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                self.delegate?.didFetch(model: value)
            case .failure(let error):
                self.delegate?.modelFailedToFetch(errorMessage: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The one thing I'm not able to do until now is to replace `Any` in the `didFetch` method of the `ModelLoaderDelegate` to be a generic-like parameter.

I tried to do it like this:

```
func didFetch<T>(info: T)
```

but in the implementer of the delegate:

```
func didFetch<T>(info: T) {
 // I need a concerete type here not a generic
}
```

Couldn't find another approach.

Comment: So, you want to use multiple instances of `ModelLoader` with one instance of `delegate`?

Comment: @Kamran No. Multiple of both.

Answer (score 1):

Instead to do this via delegate, you can make the logic by closures:

```
final class ModelLoader<ModelType> {

    let api: API
    private let client = dependencies.client

    init(api: API) {
        self.api = api
    }

    func fetchModel<ModelType>(completion: @escaping (Result<ModelType, Error>) -> ()) {
        client.performRequest(api: api, decodeTo: ModelType.self, completion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                completion(.success(value))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I think with this approach will be much easier to handle response :)

Comment: Thanks. It's a good approach, but I don't think it's worth it to just move the result handling from the modelLoader to a viewController.